# Mapping route & parameters in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In Area VIPUsers I have controller ProfileController and other controllers.

If I want every method in ProfileController to have parameter (id)
and every method in other controllers to have parameter (userid and id)
how would I map it?

Would it be

```
context.MapRoute(
  "ProfileMapping",
  "VIPUsers/Profile/{action}/{id}",
  new {controller="ManageUsers", id=""}
);
```

and then map a default one for all the controllers?

```
context.MapRoute(
  "Default",
  "VIPUsers/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{id}",
  new {action="Index", userId="", id = ""}
);
```

and...that's it? I see it's working but then it's weird...

If I go to a page on ProfileController and give it two parameters after `{action}` (VIPUsers/Profile/SomeAction/4/4/), it'd use the second mapped route. Is that correct?

thanks

and if I want the url to always require a UserId, how do I specify that?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is correct.  You will want to implement some route constraints to further narrow things down:

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-24-cs.aspx